# Android things - How to keep the led uninterruptedly ON after command mLedGpio.setValue(true)

Tags: java, android, iot, android-things

I accomplished this project: [`sample-button`](https://github.com/androidthings/sample-button/blob/master/app/src/main/java/com/example/androidthings/button/ButtonActivity.java)
But I need change this to Keep the led on when I press the button and just out it after I press the button again.

How to I can do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with replacing below callback methods in [ButtonActivity.java](https://github.com/androidthings/sample-button/blob/master/app/src/main/java/com/example/androidthings/button/ButtonActivity.java)

```
static boolean mToggle ;
@Override
    public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
        if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_SPACE) {
            // Turn on the LED
            mToggle = !mToggle;
            setLedValue(mToggle);
            return true;
        }

        return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onKeyUp(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
        if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_SPACE) {
            // Turn off the LED
           // setLedValue(false);
            return true;
        }

        return super.onKeyUp(keyCode, event);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

delete the code inside `onKeyDown` overridden method and change `setLedValue` to this:

```
private void setLedValue(boolean value) {
    try {
        mLedGpio.setValue(!mLedGpio.getValue());
    } catch (IOException e) {
        Log.e(TAG, "Error updating GPIO value", e);
    }
}
```

(you are better deleting onKeyDown than onKeyUp for a better user experience. From a UX perspective changing something as a key is released is a much better experience than acting when it is first pressed down.)

---

If you want to see the whole class changed it looks like this:

```
public class ButtonActivity extends Activity {

    private Gpio mLedGpio;
    private ButtonInputDriver mButtonInputDriver;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        PeripheralManager pioService = new PeripheralManager.getInstance();
        try {
            mLedGpio = pioService.openGpio(BoardDefaults.getGPIOForLED());
            mLedGpio.setDirection(Gpio.DIRECTION_OUT_INITIALLY_LOW);

            mButtonInputDriver = new ButtonInputDriver(
                    BoardDefaults.getGPIOForButton(),
                    Button.LogicState.PRESSED_WHEN_LOW,
                    KeyEvent.KEYCODE_SPACE);
            mButtonInputDriver.register();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            throw new IllegalStateException("Error configuring GPIO pins", e);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onKeyUp(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
        if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_SPACE) {
            toggleLedValue();
            return true;
        }    
        return super.onKeyUp(keyCode, event);
    }

    /**
     * Update the value of the LED output.
     */
    private void toggleLedValue() {
        try {
            mLedGpio.setValue(!mLedGpio.getValue());
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.e(TAG, "Error updating GPIO value", e);
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDestroy(){
        super.onDestroy();

        mButtonInputDriver.unregister();
        try {
            mButtonInputDriver.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.e(TAG, "Error closing Button driver", e);
        }

        try {
           mLedGpio.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
           Log.e(TAG, "Error closing LED GPIO", e);
        } 
   }  
}
```

Comment: Will I have to make changes to the breadboard and/or include or change electronic components? I ask this because: the codes worked but in some moments, after I click the button to OFF the led, it will ON and OFF until I click the button again

Comment: no you shouldn't have to make any electronics changes. Is it because you are pressing `SPACE` multiple times without realising it?

Comment: I need one more help. How to change this code http://pastebin.com/DRpZ0r8x    So that the led gets access uninterrupted and also so that I can turn on the led via button

Comment: make a new question and I will try to help you with an answer :-)